# Paste columns of different MySQL tables into an ascii file

Tags: mysql, bash, ascii, paste

I have hundreds of MySQL tables, and I would like to create an ascii table with the first column of each MySQL table.

From MySQL tables

```
table A          table B  ...  table Z
A1 A2 A3         B1 B2 B3      Z1 Z2 Z3
A1 A2 A3         B1 B2 B3      Z1 Z2 Z3
A1 A2 A3         B1 B2 B3      Z1 Z2 Z3
```

to an ascii file

```
A1 B1 ... Z1
A1 B1 ... Z1
A1 B1 ... Z1
```

Which is the faster method?

The tables are hundreds, the columns have thousands of lines, and most of all the columns have the same number of lines (so I don't think that a "join" before the export is necessary)

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want `A1 B1 ... Z1` to be on the same line you have to use `JOIN`. And to use join you have to relate your tables somehow. Do they have any common column? If not you should at least deterministically apply sort order to all of them.

Comment: I can create an id column and join by their id. The point is that it is a slow operation and I cannot perform hundreds of joins. I was wondering if there is something faster than (mysql export of a column)+(bash `paste`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a bash expert but I do things step wise (Other experts can edit and improve my answer)

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uusrname -ppassword -Ddatabasename -s -e 'show tables'
 count=0
while read tablenames
do
 fieldname=$(mysql -uusrname -ppassword -Ddatabasename -s -e "desc $tablename" | head -2 | tail -1  | awk -F " " '{print $1}');
 echo "$tablenames,$fieldname" >> tempfile
done< $(mysql -uusrname -ppassword -Ddatabasename -s -e 'show tables')
lastcount=$(wc -l tempfile)
while read line
 do
 count=$(($count + 1))
 if [ $count -eq 1 ] 
 then
 echo "nothing to do"
 elif [ $count -lt $lastcount ]
 then
 echo $line | awk -F "," '{print "(select "$2 "from" $1")"}' >> sqlcommand.sql
 echo "union" >> sqlcommand.sql
 else 
   echo $line | awk -F "," '{print "(select "$2 "from" $1");"}' >> sqlcommand.sql
 done < tempfile

 mysql -uusrname -ppassword -Ddatabasename << sqlcommand.sql >> outputasciifile.txt
```

Comment: change username password and database name according to yours